# Google Takeout Backup Missing Google Photos Albums

Tags: google, google-photos, google-takeout

[Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com) is not showing all of the saved albums from my Google Photos account from the Takeout options menu when selecting *Choose specific Photos data for your export*.

There is a discrepancy of 37 missing albums from the Google Takeouts options menu compared to the full set of 65 albums saved in my Google Photos account.

After investigating a sample set of albums, this issue seems to be related to whether the albums are shared with others.

- All of the missing albums I've investigated so far are owned by me AND shared with others.
- All of the albums that do successfully show in Takeout are owned by me and NOT shared with others.

**Potential solution**: Download albums manually from Google Photos directly.

I've submitted a support ticket to Google to help debug this issue (Case ID: 1-6500000033182).